# WinForm chart control: Change size of chart when saving it to a file

Tags: c#, winforms, size, save, charts

is there a way to change size of chart when using method `Chart.SaveImage()` from the source code?

Right now the only way I found to set the size of chart, is resize the form on which chart control (`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`) sits. Can I explicit set its width and height? Trying to change `Chart.Size`, `Chart.Width` or `Chart.Size` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right. The solution was so obvious that I couldn't found it thou 3 days - I had setted `Chart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill`, so changing `Size` property doesn't affect. After modified it to `DockStyle.None` I could change chart's size and (finally!) save it with appropriative width and height.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it by redefining the Size property of the chart :

```
var ch = new Chart();
ch.Size = new Size(600, 250);
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Perhaps adding a bit more to show context to the OP and others?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to save it to a memory stream, then use the Image class to change dimensions and then save it to file.

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(4096))
{
   myChart.SaveImage(ms,ImageFormat.Png);
   using(Bitmap img = Image.FromStream(ms))
   {
     using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
       g.DrawImage( b, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight );
     }
     img.Save("where\to\save\chart.png",ImageFormat.Png);
   }
}
```

Comment: Still no effect. Image has the same width/hight like original chart.